# Simulating rowspan with css and divs?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

Hi I am trying to simulate the rowspan property on css using divs and  tags, so it can be changed on a:active = double height, but at the moment it grows from two rows to three rows.

It only works when the first column its expanded, if I expand the second, third, etc then it would grow to three rows.

Here its the sample code that works, and it remains in two rows.

```
<div style="float:left;width:750px;text-align:center;height:30px;">

   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px;height:30px;">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">2</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">3</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">4</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px;">5</a>

   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
</div>
```

But If I do the following :

```
<div sytle="width:750px;text-align:center;height:30px;float:left">
<!--Row 1---->
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px;height:30px;">2</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">3</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">4</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px;">5</a>
<!--Row 2---->
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
   <a href="#" style="float:left;width:149px">1</a>
 </div>
```

Then it would grow to three rows.

What I am trying to do its a two row tabs, so when you select the one at the top it would expand the row to indicate that its been selected.

Because there are 5 elements at the top and 4 in the bottom, when you select the one at the top its when it needs to expand taking the space of the missing element below.

Comment: Just a side-note. If it is a table you are creating, can't you use TABLE element? If you want to use "semantically clean" solutions, then lists should be marked up by `UL` or `OL` and contain `LI` elements to separate list items.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I can't use a table because I need to change the rowspan property form css when hyperlink have been clicked, and css have not got rowspan property.

Comment: Can you not use a bit of Javascript to help?  You really should mark up the text with the right semantics if you can as naivists says.

Comment: Can you use Javascript? If so then use a `<table>` and a library like jQuery.

Comment: I guess I could but I would like to avoid using javascript if possible and only use css, if not I would have to use javascript. Thanks.

Comment: About jquery, I never used before :-(, I think I am going to have to start learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript (and jQuery) will let you use the easier to understand -- and semantically appropriate -- `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes of `table` cells.

jQuery is very easy to learn! And you'll find lots of help here on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I am making the assumption that the questioner has some familiarity with programming :)

Comment: Hi MDCore, lets say that not as much as I would like, I do some javascript, vbscript but unfortunatly not much more due my work.
Trying to learn on my own time, but there isn't much, busy life.